# Custom Salesforce Button with DocuSign to Sign Now, then Host in Person Signing Session

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a custom button on a custom object in Salesforce to pull Docusign templates that both Signer1 and Signer2 need to sign.  Signer1 will always be the Sender.  What I'd like to be able to do is go straight from Sender to Sign. Now to Host in Person session for second signer.  The way it is working now, the Sender goes to Sign Now and when they finish, they have to go to Email and open the document to host the sign in person session.  Is there a way to edit my button code to bypass the email and go right into the hosted signing session where Signer 2 will Sign now?

Here is my button

```
CRL:
CRL='Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};FirstName~{!User.FirstName};SignNow~1,Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};FirstName~{!User.FirstName};SignInPersonName~{!Job__c.Client_Full_Name__c};Role~Role2;RoutingOrder~2';
```

Answer (score 0):

SignNow~1 only applies to the first recipient. Unfortunately, DocuSign itself can't go from directly signing as one recipient to signing as another, SignInPerson notwithstanding. If it's required for the host to sign first then going to the email is your best bet. However, if the sender doesn't need to sign first then you can swap the recipient order and have them host, then complete the envelope via email.

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured it out- changing the CRL as follows allows for two embedded signings back to back as we were hoping.

```
CRL='Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};FirstName~{!User.FirstName};Role~Designer;RoutingOrder~1;SignNow~1,Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};FirstName~{!User.FirstName};SignInPersonName~{!Job__c.Client_Full_Name__c};Role~Client;RoutingOrder~2;SignNow~1,LoadDefaultContacts~0;'
```